# class function is not included from module

Tags: ruby

Trying to inject my own function (say check) to Float class. When I am doing from a module it is not injected to Float class. Please see the following snippets.

```
irb(main):001:0> module QA
irb(main):002:1>   class Float
irb(main):003:2>     def self.check
irb(main):004:3>     end
irb(main):005:2>   end
irb(main):006:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):007:0> include QA
=> Object
irb(main):008:0> Float.respond_to?(:check)
=> false
irb(main):009:0> extend QA
=> main
irb(main):010:0> Float.respond_to?(:check)
=> false
irb(main):011:0> class Float
irb(main):012:1>   def self.check
irb(main):013:2>   end
irb(main):014:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):015:0> Float.respond_to?(:check)
=> true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
module QA
  class Float
    def self.check
    end
  end
end
```

Is creating/modifying the class `QA::Float`, not `Float`. Try doing

```
QA::Float.respond_to?(:check)
```

And you'll see.

You could do something like this instead:

```
module QA
    def self.included(klass)
        Float.class_eval "def self.check;end"
    end
end

include QA
Float.respond_to?(:check)
# true
```

Some useful references:

- [`class_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000437)
- [`included`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000458)

Answer (score 2):

You have added the method to the `QA::Float` class, not the `Float` class. If you want to add the method to the `Float` class, you should do

```
module QA
  class ::Float
    # stuff
  end
end
```

Or even better just

```
class Float
  # stuff
end
```

Comment: @Harikrishnan R, as far as I remember `::` before a class name refers this class to its parent's class which is `Object`, but by defaults we can actually just type `class Float` to mean `class ::Float`. CMIIW Jorg & mu.